# How to change the cursor height in vscode?

Tags: linux, unix, visual-studio-code

I would like to know if there's any way to change the height of the blinking cursor in vscode. Thanks for any help.

/* I'm only writing this for the sake of getting my question passed.
I seriously don't have anything to add to the main question /*

Comment: There isn't any way to change the cursor height (other than fontSize).  Are you just trying to make it more obvious?

Comment: I'm just trying to make the cursor height on par with the font size. Without decreasing the line height or making the fonts bigger

Answer (score 1):

It seems there's no way to do it (yet).
You might wanna comment on this issue though: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/100492